# using "now" in elasticsearch results in "could not read the current timestamp" error

Tags: date, elasticsearch

using a "now" in my range query as shown below

```
 "range":{
                  "metadata_fields.time_start":{
                     "lte":"now",
                     "gt":"now-7d"
                  }
               }
```

results in an error as shown below

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "could not read the current timestamp"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "memsnippet_idx_1.1",
        "node" : "XDHi_2BbSQGb33IHDasxfA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "parse_exception",
          "reason" : "could not read the current timestamp",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "features that prevent cachability are disabled on this context"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I upgraded to 7.11 today, my index.requests.cache.enable is true. Not sure why ES cannot read the current date?

edit 1:

```
"aggregations":{
      "named_entities":{
         "significant_terms":{
            "gnd":{
               "background_is_superset":false
            },
            "field":"predicted_fields.named_entities.display.keyword",
            "size":10000,
            "background_filter":{
               "bool":{
                  "filter":[
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "owner_id":{
                              "query":8,
                              "operator":"and"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "range":{
                           "metadata_fields.time_start":{
                              "lte":"now-7d"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "should":[
                     
                  ],
                  "must":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

This is my significant aggregations query that is not working, "now" works in a range query when filtering but not in this aggregations.

Comment: you query looks fine. Can I see the output of GET memsnippet_idx_1.1/_mapping ?

Comment: so "now" does work in a range query, but when used in the aggregations context as above, it returns that error.

Comment: I just confirmed that "now" works in the background filter, but "now-7d" results in the error. "now-7d" works in the regular range query